# How can I style the CSS content for print media?

Tags: css, pdf, printing

I am using the following CSS for the footer, when generating PDFs:

```
@media print {
    @page {
        @bottom-left {
            font-size: 9px;
            content: "This should be blue\00000a
            Contact: whatever\00000a
            President: Something something, Something Something, \00000a
            Address: Some very long address\00000a
            Bank: The banking details";
            white-space: pre;
        }
        @bottom-right {
            content: counter(page) "/" counter(pages)
        }
    }
}
```

This is working fine, but I need a couple of improvements in the `bottom-left` section:

- `This should be blue` should be in blue color
- The words `Contact:`, `President:`, `Address:` and `Bank:` should be **bold**.

How can I style the CSS content?

Comment: My suggestion would be to put the footer content in your HTML instead. Then just style it `display: none` for `@media screen`.

Comment: @BrettDonald Thanks, but it seems difficult to simulate the semantics of the CSS statements`@page`, `@bottom-right` and `@bottom-left`: the content appears on every page, on the footer. No idea how to simulate that with HTML. Do you have a suggestion?